# Linked In invitation api using NSMutable request

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, nsurl

Am using the following code to send an invite to another linked in account using email id. The problem is that it turns out no invitation request is received. Please help...

```
   -(void)sendInviteTo:(NSDictionary*) member WithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completionBlock
    {
        GlobalHandler *gb=[GlobalHandler getObject];
        [gb.tokenHandler linkedinAuthTokenWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *authToken, NSError *error)
         {
             if(!error)
             {
                     NSString *firstName=[member valueForKey:@"firstName"];
                     NSString *lastName=[member valueForKey:@"lastName"];
                         NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json",authToken];
                         NSLog(@"invite str=%@",str);
                         NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest
                                                       requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:4.0];


                 NSString *messageToPerson = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/people/email=%@",[member valueForKey:@"emailId"]];
                 NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:messageToPerson,@"_path",firstName,@"first-name",lastName,@"last-name",nil], @"person",nil];
                 NSArray *valueArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:person,nil];
                 NSDictionary *values = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:valueArray,@"values", nil];
                 NSDictionary *ir = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"friend",@"connect-type",nil], @"invitation-request",nil];
                 NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:values,@"recipients",@"Invitation",@"subject",@"ConnectWithMe",@"body", ir, @"item-content", nil];

                     NSError *error2;
                     NSLog(@"%@",update);
                     NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:update options:0 error:&error2];
                    NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:postData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                 NSLog(@"%@",dict);

                 [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
                     [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                     [request setHTTPBody:postData];

                 NSURLResponse *response;
                     NSError *error=nil;
                     NSData *connection=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                     if(!error)
                     {
                         NSError *error1;
                           NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:connection options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error1];
                         NSLog(@"%@",dict);
                         completionBlock(YES,nil);

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         completionBlock(NO,error);

                     }

                 }

                 }];


    }
```

Comment: Is there any logs? Error logged?

Comment: @Larme No error Mate !

Comment: But you don't read a lot of the various `NSError` you use. With a breakpoint, does your app goes through your code?

Comment: @ Larme
Of course i did ... but there is no response coming for the request..

Comment: What happens when you log `NSData *connection`?